# Como renderizar Action acessando controller neste caso?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou usando um template pronto e faço o usdo do bootstrap, porém a transação de menus é feita através de animações em javascript e com o uso da tag `<Section>` do html, como da seguinte forma:

```
<section class="section" id="registerProfessionalUser">
        <div class="container">            
            @Html.RenderAction("Create", "ProfessionalUser")
        </div>
    </section>
```

Porém quando clico no botão ele não renderiza a página que quero com este `@Html.RenderAction("Create", "ProfessionalUser)`

e é justamente o que preciso fazer, se eu usar o `RenderPage` ele até rendereiza o Html, porém não passa pela Action `Create` que é o que eu preciso (e também creio que não seja uma boa prática), pois nesta action ela retorna para a View duas listas que preciso usar.

Action Create:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ProfessionalSpecializationDAO pSpecializationDAO = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO();
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization = pSpecializationDAO.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0);            

            ProfessionalTypeDAO pTypeDAO = new ProfessionalTypeDAO();
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalType = pTypeDAO.ListProfessionalType(0);

            return View();
        }
```

View Create:

```
@using ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Models
@model ManyLife.ASP.Models.ProfessionalUser

<style>
    .editor-field input {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="container row" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <h2 class="text-center title">Novo Profissional</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdProfessionalUser)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdProfessionalUser)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalUser)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReEmail)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReEmail)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReEmail)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RePassword)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RePassword)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RePassword)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdProfessionalRegister)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdProfessionalRegister)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalRegister)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdProfessionalSpecialization)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;">
                    <label>Especializações:</label>
                    @{
                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization)
                        {
                            <label>specialty</label>
                        }
                        Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdProfessionalSpecialization);                       
                    }
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;">
                    <label>Tipos:</label>
                    @{
                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListProfessionalType)
                        {
                            <label>specialty</label>
                        }
                    }
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está tentando cai mais dentro do conceito de `Actions` com `PartialViews`. Portanto, são necessárias algumas pequenas mudanças no seu código.

### Html Principal

```
<section class="section" id="registerProfessionalUser">
    <div class="container">            
        @Html.Action("ProfessionalUser")
    </div>
</section>
```

### Seu Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ProfessionalUser()
{
    ProfessionalSpecializationDAO pSpecializationDAO = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO();
    ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization = pSpecializationDAO.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0);            

    ProfessionalTypeDAO pTypeDAO = new ProfessionalTypeDAO();
    ViewBag.ListProfessionalType = pTypeDAO.ListProfessionalType(0);

    return PartialView(new ProfessionalUser());
}
```

A View está ok.

Comment: Esta dando o seguinte erro no VS:
"Erro ao executar a solicitação filho do manipulador 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."

No navegador aparece:
"A public action method 'ProfessionalUser' was not found on controller 'ManyLife.ASP.Controllers.HomeController'."

Comment: Você modificou o nome do método no `Controller`, conforme eu indiquei na resposta? De `Create` para `ProfessionalUser`?

Comment: Sim, troquei tudo como esta ali

Comment: "A public action method 'ProfessionalUser' was not found on controller 'ManyLife.ASP.Controllers.HomeController'." A InnerException me levou até aqui, porém, não faço requisição ao HomeController em nenhum momento. Só se o ChilgActionOnly o chama de alguma forma, se for, também não sei como resolver.

Comment: Essa `Action` precisa estar no `Controller` que chama a `View`, senão não vai mesmo funcionar.

Comment: Deixo nos 2 controllers então?

Comment: O ideal é deixar em um só, mas faça funcionar primeiro. Depois você remove um deles.